# Найти процент повторяющегося элемента в списке Python

Tags: python, массивы, list, проценты

```
a = []  
for j in range(20):  
    a.append(randint(0,10))
a.sort()
print(a)

b = [x for x, j in Counter(a).items() if j > 1] #нахожу числа, которые повторяются

c = random.choices(b, k = 1) #выбираю любое число из списка b  
print("random number:", c)

for j in res:  
    res = (длина повторяющегося элемента) * 100 / len(a)

print("procent =", res)
```

Решил поэксперементировать со списками и наткнулся на проблему. Мне нужно подсчитать количество элементов, которые повторяются, но что-то у меня не получается.

Comment: и на какую проблему наткнулись?

Comment: нужно найти длину элемента, который выбрался рандомно

Comment: т.е. сколько он раз встречается в списке? или под повторяющийся элемент понимается последовательный элемент?

Comment: да, мне нужно найти сколько в общем этого элемента в списке. к примеру a = [1, 2, 1, 3], то тут 1 встречается 2 раза и мне надо это как-то узнать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - я поправил ваш код до рабочего состояния:

```
from random import randint, choices
from collections import Counter

a = []  
for j in range(20):  
    a.append(randint(0,10))
a.sort()
print(a)

cnt = Counter(a)

b = [x for x, j in cnt.items() if j > 1] #нахожу числа, которые повторяются

c = choices(b, k = 1)[0] #выбираю любое число из списка b  
print("random number:", c)

res = cnt[c] * 100 / len(a)

print("procent =", res)
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10]
random number: 4
procent = 25.0
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, теперь мое дело - разобраться в этом. К Вам только один вопрос, почему после c = choices(b, k = 1)[0]  стоят [0]. Без них выдает ошибку, но почему?

Comment: @Rodion Потому что `choices` выдаёт **список** (хотя и из одного числа), а вам нужно просто число :)  Я через `[0]` беру первый элемент списка

Answer (score 4):

способ 1: универсальный

```
import random

size = 20
arr = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(size)]

stats = {}

for i in arr:
  if i in stats:
    stats[i] += 1
  else:
    stats[i] = 1

print(stats[random.choice(arr)])
```

способ 2: простой

```
import random

size = 20
arr = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(size)]

print(arr.count(random.choice(arr)))
```